# How to make a screen recorder in python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a screen recorder in python, I found a way to capture still images, can I compile these images into a video format? Is there anything framework I can use? thank you for any suggestions, here is the script for single images:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

time.sleep(5)
ImageGrab.grab().save("screen_capture.jpg", "JPEG")
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can compile them to video format. [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is a ***phenomenal*** command-line tool that can be run from inside python provided it is installed and on your path.

Here is a great tutorial on how to take still images and turn them into a video:
http://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/

Comment: The link is broken.